# How can I modify my cookie value before following a 302 redirect in urllib2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

I am trying to authenticate to a web application. I need to POST credentials and a cookie value to the page, it will reply with a new cookie value, then I need to follow the redirect with that new cookie value.

Currently my script fails to authenticate because it follows the redirect using my old cookie value.

Comment: Edit your question and show your relevant code. Also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question for anyone with same issue as me in the future.

Rather than trying to handle cookies and session data with urllib2, I'm now using mechanize (http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/doc.html)

Not only does it handle cookies on its own, but it implements the entire urllib2 interface. This means you won't have to re-write your code if you've already started with urllib2 like I had.